# How to set a splash screen in react-native app after login

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, splash-screen

I have a launch screen in my app while launching or opening the app at initially. It was implemented in launchscreen in ios folder.

But how can I implement another splash screen after successful login with my app.

Just say welcome to our app

Comment: Just navigate your new Screen after every successfull login attempt. If you have code base with you post it here ! We can help then

Comment: Add SpalshScreen - ViewController, in that add welcome UILable or whatever u want on that controller and navigate that controller after successfully login.